# Bayesian statistics for the working scientist

Tags: bayesian

What is a good resource that explains Bayesian statistics for an experimental scientists who already use Frequentist statistics? What are the Bayesian analogues for all the tools working scientists use, like ANOVA and linear regression (and how do the Bayesian analogues compare), and what software can be used to perform the Bayesian methods? I've heard people arguing that we should publish Bayesian "likelihood ratios" instead of doing significance testing. How would one do this?

Comment: start by looking at the answers to [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125/what-is-the-best-introductory-bayesian-statistics-textbook)

Comment: @Jules you pose a lot of good questions, many of which would be good standalone questions. As this question stands, it may be too broad to get an answer that would do the question justice. I would close this one and ask the questions independently.

Comment: The list of books Karl links to is a good starting point. Regarding software you might want to take a look at [BUGS](http://www.mrc-bsu.cam.ac.uk/bugs/welcome.shtml).

Comment: Please ask more defined questions or use [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) to discuss about this.