# What is a good book about the philosophy behind Bayesian thinking?

Tags: bayesian, references, philosophical

What is a good book about Bayesian philosophy, contrasting subjectivists against objectivists, explaining the view of probability as state of knowledge in Bayesian statistics, etc.? Maybe Savage's book?

At first I thought Berger (1986) could work, but it is not what I am looking for. Searching for such a book just doesn't quite lead to the results I am looking for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best introductory Bayesian statistics textbook?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125/what-is-the-best-introductory-bayesian-statistics-textbook)

Comment: Barnett's book systematically compares Bayesian and frequentist approaches: http://www.amazon.com/Comparative-Statistical-Inference-Vic-Barnett/dp/0471976431

Comment: The linked thread seems to be mostly about introductions to doing Bayesian analyses, rather than the specific philosophies. This may be distinct enough to remain open.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Why isn't Berger what you were looking for?  What are the results you are looking for?  How will you recognize when you've found the kind of book you are looking for?  How will you evaluate answers?  Asking for "a good book" is vague and subjective; can you edit your question to give us more precise requirements?

Answer (score 17):

Jay Kadane's [Principles of uncertainty](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439861617) is a recent and highly coherent introduction to subjective Bayesian thinking. I reviewed it [there](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/2011/10/14/principles-of-uncertainty/) and definitely recommend it.

Comment: (+1) Great suggestion. Your own "Bayesian Choice" is another excellent option.

Comment: @Zen: Thanks! But I do not pretend at mastering the philosophy of subjectivism!!!

Comment: Anyway, Chapter 11 (A Defense of the Bayesian Choice) is very convincing.

Answer (score 9):

I'm a particular fan of [Understanding Uncertainty](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470043830) by Dennis Lindley.  I actually emailed Jay Kadane a while back to ask the same question you did, and he recommended me this book.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a recent title with a focus on regression: [Bayesian and Frequentist Regression Methods](http://www.springer.com/statistics/statistical+theory+and+methods/book/978-1-4419-0924-4)

Answer (score 8):

[Probability, The Logic of Science](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Probability-Theory-Principles-Elementary-Applications/dp/0521592712) by E.T. Jaynes, provides excellent discussions around this subject. Jaynes is on the side of Objective Bayesianism.

Related books that influenced Jaynes' book are Jeffreys' *Theory of Probability* of 1939 (1948, 1961), Good's *Probability & the Weighing of Evidence* of 1950 and Savage's *Foundations of Statistics* of 1954.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most lucid expositions of Bayesian Thinking can be found in "Bayes' Rule" by Jim Stone. The same book comes in a several versions, with accompanying R, Python and MATLAB code.

http://jim-stone.staff.shef.ac.uk/BookBayes2012/BayesRuleBookMain.html