# Non-technical reference for Bayesian probability

Tags: bayesian, references

Could anyone suggest a good, non-technical, high-level explanation of Bayesian probability?

To clarify, since some people suggested a thread with recommendations of textbooks, that isn't really what I'm after. I'm looking for something for a friend of mine whose interest is in intellectual history. He isn't trying to learn to do Bayesian analysis, he just wants to know what it does or claims to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best introductory Bayesian statistics textbook?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125/what-is-the-best-introductory-bayesian-statistics-textbook) Many more threads: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bayesian+references

Comment: [*Bayesian probability for babies*](https://www.amazon.com/Bayesian-Probability-Babies-Chris-Ferrie/dp/1492680796) is probably the least technical, but I agree with others that many good references are already given in the other thread.

Comment: Thanks @Tim, while not helpful, that is at least amusing.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out these following videos, they are non-technical but give pretty good intuition.

One is "Bayes theorem, and making probability intuitive" by 3Blue1Brown, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZGCoVF3YvM

and other is "The Bayesian Trap" by Veritasium, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R13BD8qKeTg